# browse HTML File in Swing form

Tags: java, html, swing, html-parsing

I am working in Swing in Java and i want to display the HTML page as it is in Swing Form ,
Is there any tool to display or show the HTML file the file may have links and on clicking on those links other files should be displayed . In simple word i want any control like browser to browse in Swing form . Is it possible please help me 
I dont know the code for it

thanks in advance

Comment: Try JTextPane with text/html content type

Answer (score 3):

You could use `JEditorPane`:

```
String url = "http://host/path";
JEditorPane htmlPane = new JEditorPane(url);
htmlPane.setContentType("text/html");
```

Comment: This is too much slow if the HTML is too big. How can I fix that issue ...?

Answer (score 1):

[SwingBox](http://cssbox.sourceforge.net/swingbox/) provides a Swing component for displaying HTML documents. It supports more from CSS than the standard JEditorPane. A demo is included in the package.

Answer (score 0):

Most Swing components can include html formatting, but to get the link behaviour right, they need to instance a HyperlinkListener, which are applicable to JEditorPane

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/class-use/HyperlinkListener.html

Comment: *"All Swing components can include html formatting,.."*  `JTextField` and `JTextArea` don't support rich (formatted) text.