# HTML rendering in java swing

Tags: java, html, swing, html-rendering

I'm using JEditorPane to display HTML right now, but it supports only HTML4 and CSS1 and it has problem with UTF-8 encoding. Is there anything better to render HTML? I don't want to import webkit to my project because of its size. Can you recommend me something? It would be nice if I won't need to import any lib.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13218572/java-html5-alternative-to-jeditorpane

Comment: *"JEditorPane .. but it supports only HTML4.."*  HTML 3.2  (or parts of it).

Answer (score 2):

[SwingBox](http://cssbox.sourceforge.net/swingbox/) is a Swing component for displaying HTML documents. It is based on CSSBox library which is pure Java - you don't need to link Webkit or other native libraties. A demo is included in the package. This question has been asked several times here, see for example [this quiestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12530820/browse-html-file-in-swing-form) for more references.